# Use WriteElementString with database integer

Tags: c#, xml

I'm updating an XML creation class, in C#, that is used to make an RSS feed. 
It contains the following code:

```
private void BindUpcomingEvents(IQueryable<Event> eventList, FilterParams filterParams)
   {
      var pref = MarylandCalendar.Model.Helpers.Preferences.Preferences.Get();
      var events = eventList.ToList();
      .
      .
      .
      // items
      foreach (var item in events)
      {
         xfeed.WriteElementString("chair", item.chair);
         .
         .
         .

         //xfeed.WriteElementString("person_id", String.Format("{0}", item.PersonId);
         //xfeed.WriteElementString("person_id", ((int)item.PersonId).ToString());
         //xfeed.WriteElementString("person_id", item.PersonId.ToString());
         //xfeed.WriteElementString("person_id", Convert.ToInt16(item.PersonId).ToString());
         .
         .
         .
       }
    .
    .
    .
  }
```

The database **nvarchar** fields such as "chair" (see above) have no problem be written out in an XML statement. But I can't seem to write a statement that includes an **int** field such as PersonId. You can see my attempts (commented out), based on other posts on Stackoverflow, and elsewhere on the internet. If I comment out all the WriteElementString lines extracting **int** fields, the RSS feed works as expected. But otherwise, it fails.

Any clues?

Comment: What happens when one of those lines executes?  Error, blank in XML output?...?

Comment: Fails how?  What is the _specific_ type of `item.PersonId`?  Is it nullable?

Comment: @Donbotnoot:One one of those lines is executed, the web page displays "Unfortunately some error occured. Please try again later." which is apparently a customed designed page.

Comment: @DStanley: PersonId is nullable, however for one record I tested in the series the value is not null. Maybe you're suggesting it only takes one of the records to have a null PersonId to cause the error. In that case checking for null before converting is something I should consider. Is that  what you're leading to?

Comment: @gcarterIT Yes, that is what I was getting at.

Answer (score 0):

if `PersonId` is nullable, you need to check for null first:

```
xfeed.WriteElementString("person_id", item.PersonId.HasValue 
                                    ? item.PersonId.Value.ToString() 
                                    : "null")   // or 0, or blank, or something
```

Comment: Thanks. your code likes fine but something still fails. I tried something simpler: if (item.PersonId.HasValue){}; . But that failed also.

Comment: If it helps, in the begininng I had the same issue with dates. But I use something like this for dates: xfeed.WriteElementString("created_date",      Convert.ToDateTime(item.CreatedDate).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")); . And the xml statements are generated as expected. There's something about those ints :\